# Items in Spinner visible but onItemSelected Not Working

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am a beginner in Android. I have a spinner in my android code. It takes values from room database and once selected the value will be added to the listview. I have two issues 
a) I am seeing values in my Spinner. But I am not able to select it and also onItemSelected for this spinner is not working 
b) I would like to add a delete icon in my list view along with these values so that if the user is not interested in the value he can delete it.

Please can someone help me to resolve this?

Code is provided below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
  private List<String> tasks = new ArrayList<String>();
  private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
  private ListView consultantsList;
  private Spinner spinner;

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    consultantsRepository consrepo = 
    new consultantsRepository (getApplicationContext());
    ArrayList<String> oncons = consrepo.getConsultants();
    ArrayAdapter<String> consarrayadapter = 
    new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
    oncons);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
    (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,tasks);
    ListView consultantsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListToSend);
    consultantsList.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.consSpinner);
    spinner.setAdapter(consarrayadapter);
    consarrayadapter.setDropDownViewResource
    (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener
    (new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected
        (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), item, 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            tasks.add(item);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: How many elements are in the ```ArrayList<String> oncons``` ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just 4

Comment: @DBHari how you ran this code ? without overriding onNothingSelected()  in spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener , otherwise your code look good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try-
`String item=spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();`

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It worked on both statements. Like Abhinav said it is working and also the original statement also working. I wiped out data and restarted and checked, working now. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Please can you let me know how I can add a delete icon to a list view?

Comment: use like-consultantsList.remove(position)